# Edit the question changes the idea of the question

Tags: discussion

I want to change [How to Harmonize uncommon scales?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6879/1391) question to "How to harmonize whole tone scale" to make the question simpler and focused.
 
But this is not just an edit but changes the question it self.Now the voters have voted for the orignal question not the new one right(Answerer as well)?

Is it ok?

Comment: If it makes the answers obsolete, I'd say no. I'd like to hear from the mods, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We generally don't want to see question edits that change the idea of the question. Clarifications are fine, but I think in this case the answerers have already answered the original question, which is a different question from the change you are suggesting.